# Can someone help me find an author of a deleted question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

So I spent quite a lot of time writing code for an answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68652773/how-to-find-and-print-out-empty-keys-in-json-file-in-python#68652773 and the author deleted it (maybe he feared downvotes).
I want to contact him and send my code to him. Here it is:

```
import json
whereParsedTo = ""
def find_empty_values(data):
   global whereParsedTo
   for i in data:
      whereParsedTo = i
      for x in data['area']:
         for key in x.values():
            if key == '':
               print("o",key)
            elif str(type(key)) == "<class 'dict'>":
               for item in key.values():
                  if key == '':
                     print("o",key)
with open('dat.json') as file:
   try:
      data = json.load(file)
      find_empty_values(data)
   except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
      f = open('dat.json').read()
      f = f.replace(": ,", ": 0,")
      newdata = eval(f)
      find_empty_values(newdata)
```

Comment: You can see other posts by this author at https://stackoverflow.com/users/15269714/shultz Maybe leave a (temporary, which you can clean up later) comment at one of the posts?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, though...

Comment: It would be against the law for anyone to provide you this information without a court document, if they were to have the information, Anonymous accounts are a thing

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The page returns error 404

Comment: @PetrL. It seems the account was deleted in the last few hours. If you think your solution would be valuable for others users with the same problem, you could consider writing a question and self-answer.

Answer (score 6):

So you got burned by an OP writing a question only to delete it moments later.

Sorry about that.

But, there's not a whole lot you can do.  Accept that they've decided not to get their question answered and move on.

Comment: It's a great lesson why we don't just rush in writing code. If the OP isn't invested in the question, then we don't really need to invest much time, either.